# Change elements in a list based on dict values

Tags: python

I have a list in Python with three different numbers:

```
myList = [1,2,2,3,1,3,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3]
```

And I have a dict:

```
d = {"one":1, "two":2, "three":3}
```

Is there some built in function (I was thinking something like map function) that can apply rules in dict. to python list in order to change it?

Expected result:

```
myList = ["one", "two", "two", "three", "one", "three"...]
```

Comment: flip the dictionary. {1:'one'....}

Comment: Built-in, no not really, but its not difficult to do. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revert the dict

```
>>> reverted_dict = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
```

...and use it in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [reverted_dict[i] for i in myList]
['one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

You can also use the `map()` function if you want to:

```
>>> list(map(reverted_dict.get, myList))
['one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using Pandas and Map

If you want to use pandas.Series and map, then you can do the following:

```
myList = [1,2,2,3,1,3,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3]
d = {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"}
import pandas as pd
newlist = pd.Series(myList).map(d).tolist()
print (newlist)
```

Note here that I flipped the dictionary key:values.

## Using List Comprehension

The output will be:

```
['one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

Alternate, you can do this:

```
newlist = [d[i] if i in d else None for i in myList ]
print (newlist)
```

Output will be:

```
['one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```